# Why am I getting different results with same code in D3js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I've reached an dead end in my bar chart project using d3js. I'm trying to find the sum of number of drones in different countries using data from a tsv file. Because multiple entries in the spreadsheet are from the same country I would like to add these values.

So it worked out when I ran the code once under `.attr('y')`. I double checked the spreadsheet and the sum added up. But when I ran the same conditional in the `.attr('height')` I got wonky values that messed up the bar chart. Here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
 g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Country); })
      .attr("y", function(d,i) { 

        try{
          if (data[i].Country == data[i-1].Country){

            data[i].Registration += data[i-1].Registration;
          }
          else{
            console.log(data[i-1].Country + ' ' + data[i-1].Registration);
            return data[i-1].Registration;//y(data[i-1].Registration);
          }
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log('did not work')
        }

      })
      .attr("width",20)
      .attr("height", function(d,i) { 
        try{ //SAME CODE DIFFERENT REGISTRATION VALUES

          if (data[i].Country == data[i-1].Country){
            data[i].Registration += data[i-1].Registration;
          }
        else{ console.log(data[i-1].Country + ' ' + data[i-1].Registration); return (height - data[i-1].Registration);}
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log('did not work')
        }


      });
    })
```

The tsv file looks like this:

```
Country Registration
land Islands   1
American Samoa  1
American Samoa  1
American Samoa  1
American Samoa  6
American Samoa  1
American Samoa  1
American Samoa  1
Antigua and Barbuda 1
Argentina   1
Australia   1
Australia   2
Australia   1
Australia   1
Brazil  1
Brazil  1
Brazil  1
```

I've put the [entire code](https://jsfiddle.net/vs08yezk/) on js fiddle. I'd really appreciate help, as I've spent more than a day stressing over the solution.

Comment: can you tell what exactly you want to achive.

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not working. It's missing D3, and even after fixing that there is some other error.

Comment: The reason you are seeing different result is because when doing `data[i].Registration += data[i-1].Registration;` you are actually altering the data. Notice the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) `+=`. When doing calculations in the callback to `height` your data has already been altered by the previous callback to `y`. A possible solution is provided by Cyril's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41197222/4235784).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to sum up your values:

So if your data is having multiple "American Samoa" then you need to sum up all the drones, which sums up to 12.

To do that make use of d3 `nest` to group and sum up its registration.

```
  var data_sum = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })//group by country
  .rollup(function(v) { return d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.Registration; }); })//roll up all resgistrations
  .entries(data);
```

Now this will give you the summed up data, which can be used to make the bar chart just as this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4).

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYuCS7bnNfKjVIDXIdbu?p=preview)

Comment: I added a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196660/why-am-i-getting-different-results-with-same-code-in-d3js#comment69596046_41196660) explaining why this is happening. Feel free to also include this in your answer.